# Accessing ClientID of a Control in a different TD

Tags: jquery, asp.net, clientid

I am trying to access the ClientID of a control in one  from a javascript (using jquery) call in a control in another  in order to do some client-side show and hide effects. Here's the basic structure:

```
<td>
  <asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="DoStuff" runat="server">
</td>
<td>
  <asp:TextBox ID="blah" runat="server">
</td>
```

In Scripts:

```
function DoStuff() {
  $("#<%= blah.ClientID %>").hide();
}
```

The problem I'm having, is that the function does nothing. It works fine hiding objects in the same TD, but here it doesn't seem to be able to find the control.

Comment: Did you catch the missing closing double quotes ? `$("#<%= blah.ClientID %>").hide()`

Comment: Not there. But in the actual code it is fine. Small typo.

Comment: Can you open your javascript console to see for errors ? and also remove the updatepnale for while to see the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring directly to the control on the server side, `ClientID` should including any NamingContainer information (from something like a GridView or a Repeater).  Find out what the client ID of the control is using your browser's developer tools (IE has Developer Tools, Firebug for Firefox, etc.), then debug JavaScript (with the same tool) and do a `$("#theidyoujustfound")` in the JavaScript console and see what you end up with.

It also looks like there's a missing double quote in your `DoStuff()` method; you'll want `$("#<%= blah.ClientID %>").hide();`. And I'm not sure it's necessary, but it couldn't hurt to include the parenthesis for the OnClientClient function:

```
<asp:LinkButton OnClientClick="DoStuff()" runat="server">
```

Comment: It was the parentheses. I completely passed over that after an extender yelled at me and wouldn't work until I removed them. I guess it's different for an actual control. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

To verify it can't find it, try this: `alert($("#<%= blah.ClientID %>).length);`  If it returns a number greater than zero, then the issue isn't the find.  Is the table row in a control like the `<asp:Repeater />` control?  If so, then you need to embed the script within the repeater template too.

HTH.

Comment: It is in an UpdatePanel, which is inside of a ListView. The Script is outside of the ListView. However, the alert isn't even popping up.. ideas?

Comment: Ok nvm, Ian's suggestion to add the parentheses fixed the issue. Thank you for the suggestion about the alert! :)